# Unable to convert widows epoch time to normal date time

Tags: python, windows, datetime, epoch

I am trying to parse my Google Chrome Bookmarks file.

Entries in that file have a field called `date_added` with values like `13195047309383442`

I am unable to convert this time to standard date time.

I have tried the following:

```
import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(13195047309383442).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

My initial reaction was to divide the time by 1000000 as I discovered that Windows stores the epoch time in microseconds. This resulted in following:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(13195047309383442/1000000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

'2388-02-19 21:55:09'
```

As can be seen above the year field is incorrect.

**Where am I going wrong and how do I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a windows timestamp to a Python `datetime` you need to use the Window epoch:

#### Code:

```
import datetime as dt
windows_epoch = dt.datetime(year=1601, month=1, day=1)

def datetime_from_window_ts(timestamp):
    return windows_epoch + dt.timedelta(seconds=timestamp/1e6)
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(datetime_from_window_ts(13195047309383442))
```

#### Results:

```
2019-02-19 10:55:09.383442
```

Comment: how do I convert this output to strftime output in the following format `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: The value returned is a `datetime`.  Just add the `.strftime(...)` onto the return value.  So `datetime_from_window_ts(...).strftime(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong time origin. For Unix it's 1970/1/1, for Windows it's 1601/1/1 or something. You may try his code:

```
>>> microseconds = 13195047309383442
>>> seconds, microseconds = divmod(microseconds, 1000000)
>>> days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
>>> datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days, seconds, microseconds)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 19, 10, 55, 9, 383442)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you were trying to parse the Chrome bookmarks file but from what I have read the Chrome bookmark timestamps don't use the Unix 1970 date. It uses the 1601-01-1 date  (which is why your date overshoots the Feb 19th 2019 date you might be expecting).

Check out this resource:
http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Chrome_bookmarks

And this converter tool, it actually has a Python snippet of how the conversion is done.
https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit